# Do we know how old Kakashi is?

Tags: naruto

I've been wondering, since I can't find an exact age... While watching these filler episodes, he appears as the ANBU Kakashi, who was leading his team. Being the Senpai of Itachi he looks exactly (maybe for me) like he does in the present day... Is this a coincidence? Or couldn't the animators be bother to add additional "lines" to his face? Note that we've seen the newborn Naruto, that would mean that Kakashi looks the same as he did 17-18 years ago..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [this timeline](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/User%3aTimeel39/Timeline) and the following data

```
September 15 Birth day Kakashi
Academy Grad. Age   5
Chūnin Prom. Age    6
```

We can tell that Kakashi was born 14 years before the 9-tails attack. Using the information that the Akatsuki dead line was 18 years after the 9-tails attack. we can tell that Kakashi should be roughly 32 years old.

Comment: pretty interesting...+1!

Comment: btw...interesting,that we got info about Sarutobi...but nothing from earlier times, nor the First or the Second Hokage...

Comment: @Rinneg4n Tons of info scatterd around. I believe the last time that time line got updated was in Januari. So it might be lacking some of the more recent info we got ^^

Answer (score 0):

at the time of pain he was 30 so one year has passed in the forth great ninja war so he is 31. mr.dimitri mx you were so so close by one year. and also have we considered that kakashi died by pain and was revived so technically he restarted his life when pain revived him so isnt he really one years old.

Comment: Please format the question and use the basic english guidlines like large and lower case. This is not the only answer you wrote like this. We do not want to edit all of your answers. Also press from time to time the enter key. It is much easier to read if you do so...

Comment: I don't think revival counts as life time reset, he still has the mental state and physical state of a 30 year old.